# Use a button to add other buttons, editText etc.

Tags: android, button, automation

I need to be able to add buttons to a layout using an "add" button. The problem is that I need each button to have an OnClickListener()/onClick method. I was thinking every time the "add" button is pressed then i would add a new button to an array but im not sure add the listener and implement an onClick method for each button I create.

```
   public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final SmartChronometer chrono = (SmartChronometer) findViewById(R.id.chrono);

    final Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (chrono.isRunning())
                 chrono.pause();
            else {

                chrono.chronoStart();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

I need to add  chronomoter,button and listeners every time I click an "Add" button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set all the clicklisteners as you wich!

call `findViewById(R.id.btnSecond).setVisibility(View.GONE);` on creat, then when clickin the first button

```
Button btnSecond;
```

...

```
  public void onClick(View v) {

    findViewById(R.id.btnSecond).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 if (btnSecond.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE); {    
    findViewById(R.id.btnThird).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);}    
    }
```

this way you can put all your information in the java file and all buttons in xml, but they will be hidden until click.

This is one way, other answer my come. Good Luck :)

Comment: what about when creating the third button, fourth...? unless i add a switch statement thats sets each button btnThird btnFourth etc

Comment: sorry didn’t understand your question. you want to know how can you know when to add a thirbutton after the second has been added?

Answer (score 0):

implements OnClickListener

```
Button add = (Button) findViewById (R.id.addButton);
add.setOnClickListener (this);

List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList <Button>();
for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size (); i++){
       buttons.get (i).setOnClickListener (this);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v){
      for (int i = 0; i < buttons.size (); i++){
               if (v.getId () == buttons.get (i).getId ()){
                       // do stuff you want
               }else if (v.getId() == R.id.addButton){
                     //add button
               }
       }
}
```

Hope this will work, didnt test it.